# Como fazer um http request com php com autenticação e esperando um arquivo em resposta?

Tags: php, libcurl, http-request

Estou usando um serviço de Text to Speech e gostaria de utilizar ele em um php que 
estou montando.

O Problema é que nunca fiz isso que a api pede e nem sei por onde começar.

na documentação é fornecido este tipo de informação

```
GET https://txttovoice.org/v/tts?v=1.1&text=Hello+world

Headers:
Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_DE_ACESSO
Accept-Language: pt-BR
```

com que eu faço um php enviar essas headers neste link e receber um download de um arquivo em troca e salvar na mesma pasta que o meu arquivo php esta?

na api ele fornece um curl tbm

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_DE_ACESSO" -H "Accept-language: pt-BR" https://txttovoice.org/v/tts?v=1.1&text=Hello+world" -o arquivo.wav
```

qual seria a forma mais simples de eu fazer isto funcionar?

Comment: [Este link](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) não é a solução mastigada mas pode te colocar no caminho. Você faz a requisição pelo curl e pode salvar a resposta em um arquivo ou processar o conteúdo da resposta da requisição da maneira como quiser.

Comment: vo tenta obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos traduzir o CURL:

- `curl` : Inicia o CURL.
- `-k` : Define para modo inseguro, não verificando o SSL.
- `-H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_DE_ACESSO"` Define o cabeçalho de `Authorization` com o valor de `Bearer TOKEN_DE_ACESSO`.
- `-H "Accept-language: pt-BR"` : Define o cabeçalho de `Accept-language` com valor de `pt-BR`
- `"https://txttovoice.org/v/tts?v=1.1&text=Hello+world"` : Define o website que quer se conectar.
- `-o arquivo.wav` : Define o local de saída do resultado.

---

Agora vamos portar isto para o PHP, na mesma ordem:

```
// Inicia o CURL:
$ch = curl_init();

// Adiciona as opções:
curl_setopt_array($ch, [

      // Modo inseguro:
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,

      // Adiciona os cabeçalhos:
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
           'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_DE_ACESSO',
           'Accept-language: pt-BR',
      ],

      // Define o URL para se conectar:
      CURLOPT_URL => 'https://txttovoice.org/v/tts?v=1.1&text=Hello+world',

      // Saída:
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true

]);

// Executa:
$resultado = curl_exec($ch);

// Encerra CURL:
curl_close($ch);
```

A variável `$resultado` possuirá o resultado retornado pelo website, dessa forma se deseja salvar em algum local utilize o `file_put_contents()`.

```
file_put_contents('nome_arquivo.formato', $resultado);
```

Essa é uma das maneiras mais fácies, porém pode haver problemas relacionados a memoria e por isso pode tratar o armazenamento diretamente no CURL, que irá corrigir o problema.

---

Para isso a solução é utilizar o `CURLOPT_FILE`, que basicamente fará exatamente o que o `-o` faz.

```
$escreverArquivo = fopen('nome_arquivo.formato', 'w+');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, [

      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,

      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
           'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_DE_ACESSO',
           'Accept-language: pt-BR',
      ],
      CURLOPT_URL => 'https://txttovoice.org/v/tts?v=1.1&text=Hello+world',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_FILE => $escreverArquivo

]);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

fclose($escreverArquivo);
```

*Lembre-se que o `TOKEN_DE_ACESSO` deve ser o `token`, que geralmente é obtido numa requisição anterior, em caso de OAuth, por exemplo. Isso deve estar mencionado na documentação da API, mas isto não foi mencionado na pergunta para que pudesse responder.*

Comment: certíssimo, já ta funcionando aqui . muito obrigado pelo seu tempo