# Autenticar uma API Json com PHP

Tags: php, json

Preciso fazer uma autenticação de usuário em um API formato JSON, tenho toda a documentação desta API.
Depois de autenticar consigo fazer as consultas que preciso.

o Desenvolvedor diz que eu precioso disto para autenticar.

Para acessar a API é necessário passar dois headers, são eles:

```
Authorization: {String}
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

Authorization: {Eu ja tenho a STRING}
```

o que eu preciso fazer para logar em php?
Onde eu posso encontrar material a respeito de como fazer?

Comment: Veja se isto ajuda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184861/como-fazer-um-http-request-com-php-com-autenticação-e-esperando-um-arquivo-em-re

Comment: Não consegui com o exemplo que me passou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se precisa apenas desses dois cabeçalhos utilize o `-H` do cURL. ;)

Dessa forma ficaria:

```
curl -H "Authorization: {String}" -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" https://site-alvo.com
```

No PHP, entretanto, ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```
// Inicia o CURL, definindo o site alvo:
$ch = curl_init('https://site-alvo.com');

// Adiciona as opções:
curl_setopt_array($ch, [

      // Equivalente ao -H:
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
           'Authorization: {String}',
           'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      ],

      // Permite obter resposta:
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true

]);

// Executa:
$resultado = curl_exec($ch);

// Encerra CURL:
curl_close($ch);
```

Dessa forma obtenha a resposta utilizando:

```
var_dump($resultado);
```

---

No entanto *possivelmente* existe um erro na própria pergunta. O `Authorization` possui o padrão `Authorization: <type> <credentials>`, isso foi [determinado pela W3C](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945).

Por exemplo, no caso de HTTP Auth Basic, padrão:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

Isso é `Authorization:` `Basic` + `BASE64(Login:Senha)`.

Em outros casos, padrões, utiliza o `Bearer Token`, que vem do OAuth2, [aqui tem os detalhes disto](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750).

Pessoalmente **desconheço** um tipo de:

```
Authorization: JSON {}
```

Possivelmente a chamada anterior que você faz retorna um JSON da seguinte maneira:

```
{
  "access_token":"mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM",
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "expires_in":3600,
  "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA"
}
```

Isto é exatamente o exemplo do que está [especificado aqui](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-4), logo deve utilizar o `access_token` em:

```
Authorization: Bearer mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM
```

*Mas sem a documentação especifica é impossível adivinhar!*